# Wanted but not invoked: Mockito and Retrofit

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, retrofit2, android-testing

I'm trying to unit test a call to my api using Mockito.
I took a look at all the issues already mentioned here on S.O together with the solutions, but so far, none of them have been conclusive.

MyService is an interface which holds several resources. Here's a sample:

```
public interface MyService {
@GET("/myresource")
Call<MyResponse> getDataFromServer();
}
```

Inside my Application class, I have a static class which returns an instance of MyService

```
public static MyService getApiService() {
    return mApiService;
}
```

So, from there on inside one of my classes, I make the call to the web service:

```
Call<MyResponse> call = getApiService.getDataFromServer();
call.enqueue(myCallback)
```

The rest follows with the callback method being called....

Here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SampleTest {

@Mock
private MyService mService;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<MyResponse>> callbackArgumentCaptor;

@Mock
private Call<MyResponse> mockCall;

//  Rule to trigger the creation of @Mock annotated objects.
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Test
public void testDoAction() throws NullInsteadOfMockException {
    when(mService.doSomeAction()).thenReturn(mockCall);
    mService.doSomeAction();
    verify(mockCall).enqueue(callbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
    }
}
```

Here's the error I have once I run the test:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
    mockCall.enqueue(
    <Capturing argument>
    );
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I have the same error even if use MockitoJunitRunner (in place of AndroidJunitRunner) and initialize my mock objects inside a setup method I define like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Mockito version : 2.7.19

I want to be able to test the API response, so I mocked the API service, defined a captor for the retrofit Callback

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit strange what you're trying to do here. You're testing a class, but you mock it. You should test the real class - `MyService`. I assume that your service looks a bit like:

```
public class MyService {
  private final Call<MyResponse> call;

  public MyService(Call<MyResponse> call) {
    this.call = call;
  }

  public void doSomeAction() {
    call.enqueue(...);
  }
}
```

Ideally you should have something like:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SampleTest {

  private MyService mService;

  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<MyResponse>> callbackArgumentCaptor;

  @Mock
  private Call<MyResponse> mockCall;

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

   mService = new MyService(mockCall);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDoAction() throws NullInsteadOfMockException {
    mService.doSomeAction();

    verify(mockCall).enqueue(callbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
   }
}
```

So the idea is to mock all the dependencies of the class you're unit testing and pass them to the class somehow. Here I'm injecting them in the constructor. I don't know if this is the case for you, but a setter or a field works too.

Then the test simply calls the real method in the service class and if this method is suppose to enqueue the call, then the verify should pass.

The reason it doesn't work in your case is because you're mocking the service so when you call `mService.doSomeAction()` this doesn't call your implementation, which I suppose should call `enqueue`. This is why the verify fails. In other words, it's true that `enqueue` is never called on the call object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Fred, but MyService is a simple interface with callbacks like this:  @GET("myresoure/")
Call<ApiResponse> method();

Comment: ok, but then you should test the implementation. Interfaces have nothing to be tested. What do you actually want to test? I thought the idea was to test ``MyService`` and ensure it's doing what it's meant to.

Comment: I want to test the response sent back by the server and for that I mocked the callback using mockito's  ArgumentCaptor

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood. If you want to test what the server sends then maybe mocking is not right here. If you want to test how your code reacts to specific versions of the server response, then yes you should mock the response. However, you're not testing how your code reacts because you're testing an interface or better yet a mock.

Comment: I updated my question Fred, I hope it will be much clearer as to what I want to achieve

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. What I said still stands. You're testing ``mService.doSomeAction();`` which in your test case is a mock and in your app an interface. You should test the implementations of ``MyService`` and not mock them while testing. As I said, calling ``mService.doSomeAction();`` results in not calling the ``enqueue`` method like you want.

Comment: Thanks Fred ! It turns out as you pointed out, I'm mocking the interface, not it's implementation since it is actually the implementation that needs to be tested. Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction...Turns out a little refactoring of my code is necessary

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Fred You save my life. Thank you very much, I was searching for this answer since last 3 days but today I found it. Very helpful.